# Maximum and minimum values not printing in main () function

Tags: c++

I am doing a code on tracking how much food tigers eat in 1 week and I am tracking 3 tigers.

I am supposed to print average, maximum and minimum. Whenever I run the code it doesn't print the max or minimum, only the initialized values I have in the function. I am assuming the int main() ignores my return values completely, but I can't see why is that. I have done many functions before and I do the same code every time and call it in main

Here is the code:

```
   int main(){
 cout << "Enter whether you want to find minimum for tiger 1 2 or 3. (Please 
 only enter 0, 1 or 2): ";

 cin >> temp;

 if (temp < 0) {
     cout << "CAN'T RUN NEGATIVE NUMBERS";
     exit(2);
 }

 least(food, temp, minimum);
 cout << "\n";

  cout << "The Tiger " << temp << " has minimum: " << minimum << " ";

 cout << "\n \n ";
   }



float least(float food[][DAYS], int temp, float min) //loop for days only 
 {


minimum = food[0][0];
//temp has to be less than 3
for (int j = 0; j < DAYS; ++j) {
    if (min<food[temp][j]) {
        min = food[temp][j];
    }
}
cout << min << " ";
return max;

  }


system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can get straight to the root of the problem.

Comment: Do you mind running the code? Because I don't think I can provide what you asked or else the code would not make sense. The maximum and minimum value functions are called "Most" and "Least"

Comment: "Do you mind running the code?", I'm not sure aggressivity is the best way to get help. A minimal example would make sense. Actually, chances are that you would solve your issue yourself while preparing this minimal example.

Comment: I humbly apologize, can you please check the code now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using the return value, use the max and min argument as reference variable in your function definitions. Also the comparison in least & Most functions seems to be wrong. It should be the opposite way.

```
float least(float food[][DAYS], int temp, float &min) //loop for days only 
 {

min = food[0][0];  //temp has to be les
for (int j = 0; j < DAYS; ++j) {
    if (min>food[temp][j]) {
        min = food[temp][j];
    }
}
cout << min << " ";
return min;

 }



 float Most(float food[][DAYS], int amb, float &max) //loop for days only 
 {


 max = food[0][0];
  //amb has to be less than 3
  for (int j = 0; j < DAYS; ++j) {
    if (max<food[amb][j]) {
        max = food[amb][j];
     }
  }
  cout << max << " ";
  return max;

 }
```

Comment: I completely forgot about call by reference , thank you very much It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use your methods' return values. Replace

```
Most(food, amb, maximum);
```

and

```
least(food, temp, minimum);
```

with

```
maximum = Most(food, amb, maximum);
```

and

```
minimum = least(food, temp, minimum);
```

Comment: Says Uninitialized local variable maximum, minimum when I do that

Comment: Yeah.. Remove these parameters. `maximum = Most (food, amb)` and `minimum = least (food, temp)`  (Or actually initialize them?)